# How to make a calculation or measure by relating 3 tables in DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have three tables as follows:

**Table1: Tagret**

| Branch | Total Target Sales |
| --- | --- |
| First | 642 |
| Second | 862 |
| Third | 876 |
| ... | ... |

**Table2: Currency Codes**

| Branch | Currency Codes |
| --- | --- |
| First | A1 |
| Second | A2 |
| Third | A3 |
| ... | ... |

**Table3: USD Conversion Rate**

| Conversion Rate (Divide by this value) | Currency Codes |
| --- | --- |
| 2.3 | A1 |
| 0.34 | A2 |
| 1.5 | A3 |
| ... | ... |

Now I want to convert the **Total Target Sales** into USD. How Should I do that?

I have tried using the **RELATED** function but it is not helping, it is good for calculation over only two related tables.

```
Total Target Sales USD = 
SUMX(
    Target,
    DIVIDE(
        Target[Total Target Sales], 
        RELATED('Currency Codes'[Branch].........???)
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of relations is not relevant here: RELATED works very well.

```
Total Target Sales USD = 
SUMX(
    Target,
    DIVIDE(
        Target[Total Target Sales], 
        RELATED('USD Conversion Rate'[Conversion Rate])
    )
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

when the relationships are correctly set, it should be working fine

[image: relationships]

then simply add a calculated column

```
USD Value =
DIVIDE (
    Target[Total Target Sales],
    RELATED ( 'USD Conversion Rate'[Conversion Rate] )
)
```

[image: result]

Comment: The Relationship between Target and Currency Code is auto-detected as many may and remains inactive.

Comment: @Atif you should check your data set then... ``Currency Code-->Target relation`` should be ``one-to-many``